# Retrieving .Net managed exception system error code

Tags: c#-4.0, pinvoke

When you PInvoke native methods such as RegQueryInfoKeyEx in ADVAPI32.dll the methods return a system error code, which is incredibly useful to me. is there anyway that you can retrieve the error code for a .net managed exception?

I understand that the HResult property contains this value but I have no idea how to extract it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You can get to it with Marshal.GetHRForException().

Comment: I can get the HResult using Exception.HResult, what I need is the Windows error code not the whole HResult

Comment: Yes, you get the Windows error code with that for an IOException.  Have you tried it?  If you did and are not happy with what you got then document that in your question.